# Contents.js blocking page load chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom, google-chrome-extension

Hey guys so I'm building an extension but I have a function that is heavy when running and it's blocking the load of the page and I was wondering if it was possible to only run it after the page is fully loaded and interactive either in the script or in `manifest.json`?

I currently have it inside a `window.onload` but still blocks the interactiveness of the page.

The script:

```
async function getEAN() {
    var EANIndex;
    var body = document.body.innerText;

    if ((EANIndex = body.indexOf('EAN')) !== -1) {
        body = body.slice(EANIndex, EANIndex + 100);
        const regexExpression = RegExp(/([^EAN]*$)*\d{3}\d{4,6}\d{3,5}\d/gm);
        return body.match(regexExpression)[0]
    }
    return false
}

window.onload = function() {
    if (window.location.pathname &&
        location.hostname.indexOf(".google.com") !== -1) {
        console.log(getEAN());
    }
}
```

Would this be possible if yes how can I achieve it?

Comment: The code is trivial so the problem is your regexp, specifically the incorrect `([^EAN]*$)*`. Show us the text you want to match and its variations and we'll fix the regexp.

Comment: The text is the whole page. I already cut a bunch of it by finding the index of EAN and the regex searched a sequence of numbers after the word EAN.

Comment: Here is the example: https://regex101.com/r/jYlSAj/1 @wOxxOm

Comment: I asked you to show the part of text you want to match and define the rules for matching in order to fix the regexp. Without it, I can only guess that `\n` stands for a real newline character and that you want to match numbers following `EAN` so the regexp would be `/(?<=EAN\s*)\d{11,15}/gm`

Comment: Yhe I basically want to find the EAN in a product page so I can do some processing with my API. Tested it out in regex101 didn't work the EAN part, unfortunately. So to further examplain I can have EAN then some HTML tags or \n ... and then the EAN numbers and I want that composition of 11 to 15 numbers right after EAN

Comment: And the EAN is non inclusive meaning it will only return the numbers

Comment: Your text on regex101 is probably invalid because it uses `\n` instead of the actual newline characters. For the third time, the question is either unanswerable or is already answered by my comment above unless you provide a real example of the text or better yet the URL of the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236699/discussion-between-deadsec-and-woxxom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the content script itself is trivial, the problem is caused by *catastrophic backtracking* inside the regular expression, specifically `([^EAN]*$)*` which can match 0 characters at any place.

The solution is to use a look-behind condition:

```js
/(?<=EAN\s*)\d{11,15}/gm
```